# Global.asax.cs file is not recompiling--file is valid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, global-asax

I recently refactored some code, and a method the original Global.asax.cs file was depending on was no longer static.  When I made changes to my Global.asax.cs code to fix the compilation problem, VisualStudio Development Server is still reporting the old problem.  To make things more confusing, it's reporting the old problem with the new source code.

When I start up the development server I get the tell-tale error screen saying:

Method not found: 'System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal Example.Records.AuthenticationManager.GetPrincipleForUserName(System.String);

This original exception was located at line 54--which shouldn't matter to you, me or anyone else.  However, it matters to Development Server.  No matter what I change the code to, even completely commenting out the original code, I get the same error message.  The only difference is the snippet of code it displays.  It's currently pointing to a comment line.

So DevelopmentServer is seeing the old compiled code and VisualStudio is seeing the new code.  I can't set the breakpoint because VisualStudio is telling me the source code is different from the original version.

How can I force DevelopmentServer to see the new code that works?

Comment: +1: I had this happen to me a while back.  It was very frustrating, but I don't remember exactly what I did to make it work.

Comment: I just tried that in desparation.  Still no dice.  I was thinking that maybe the virus scanner was causing the problems (like it was with other projectes we have here).  FYI McAfee + On-Access scanning + compiling code = disaster.

Comment: New information.  I deleted all files under my obj/ and bin/ directories.  The error message changed, but I still cannot get my app running.  The new error message is "Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'Example.App.MvcApplication'"  It's as if the environment can't find the Global.asax.cs file at all.  It hasn't moved so what is going on?

Comment: More new information.  We did a fresh checkout on another person's machine and they have the same problem.  It has to be something with the project or some config file.  I'm at a loss where to look.  I'm going to attempt to create a new project and copy all my source into it to try and get past the problem.

Comment: This is a complete wild-ass-guess but try deleting all the files on c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\ (for what ever version of .NET you have.)

Comment: Wait, if the problem is also happening to somebody else in a different machine then deleting the temporary files might not help. Oh well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have since found the real reason why this occurs, and it also affects the "Symbols not loaded for this class" problem when you try to debug your application.  The problem has to do with the path to the DLLs.  If your web application is part of a larger solution, and someone edits the solution configuration, Visual Studio will alter the build output path.

By default, the build output path for Debug is located in the ~\bin\ folder.  This is so that Cassini can find the DLLs and the PDB files.  When someone edits the master configuration and changes the architecture, VisualStudio will automatically update the target output directory to "~\bin{architecture}\Debug".  You have to manually go into the properties for your project and set the output directory to "bin\" for debug again.  Once you do that, it will work again.

--- Original Answer:

The only thing I could do to make it work was create a new project and copy all my code in.  It's not a good answer, but its the best I could come up with.  Same exact code ran like a champ.  After going through the project file line by line, I could not find anything that would explain the behavior I was seeing.